# Creating a concatenated list in Excel 2010 that searches my rows for all unique values

Tags: excel-2010

I have an issue I need help with, and I will do my best to explain it.

I am using Excel 2010. I have a vertical list that lists product numbers and how many stores they occur at with a price. For example:

Amazon | Product A | $100

Best Buy | Product A | $200

Target | Product B | $300

Target | Product A | $100

Walmart | Product B | na

Best Buy | Product C | na

I want to write a formula in each row that basically searches my lists and gives me a list of every occurrence at which product A occurs AND has a price. So in the next cell for any row where Product A is, I want it list out "Amazon Best Buy Target." And any row that has Product B in it, I want it say "Target" (But NOT Walmart, since there is no price), and Product C should return na or an error or something, because there is no price

I'd like to do this in as few extra columns as possible, but I'm open to anything that will help! I'd also be open to learning if there is any macro/VBA solutions around this, too. I'm not too familiar with VBA coding, but would like to learn more.

Comment: What have you tried? Please see the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to get the best results on this site. Welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, I ultimately ended up using this site's VBA code to solve my problem:

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/12/20/excel-udf-lookup-and-return-multiple-values-concatenated-into-one-cell/

It is pretty finicky code in regard to ranges, and it is not very fast to calc on larger spreadsheets, but it does get the job done.

I ended up having to write a specific join formula that combined the factors I was looking for, and repeating this join in a 2nd column to get the code to work properly, but it only ended up adding 3 extra columns to my spreadsheet and ultimately got me the results I was looking for as described above.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable seems exactly well-suited, though your mention of "as few extra columns as possible" may be an issue. However there is no need for a PT to be on the same sheet.

[image: SO25919207 example]

Following some clarification and assuming `Amazon` is in A2 and the PivotTable (in F1) is a named range `Larray`, please try in D2:

```
=IF(C2="na","",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(VLOOKUP(B2,Larray,2,0)>0,G$2)&" "&IF(VLOOKUP(B2,Larray,3,0)>0,H$2)&" "&IF(VLOOKUP(B2,Larray,4,0)>0,I$2)&" "&IF(VLOOKUP(B2,Larray,5,0)>0,J$2),"FALSE","")))
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: This is not really the answer I'm looking for. In the end, I need a column that lists ALL occurrences of Product A in every row that Product A occurs. For the example I'm listing, this is how I would ideally need it to look (but I'm working with thousands of rows): http://screencast.com/t/NT0dk24rAKj

Answer (score 0):

This formula will output what you need, but not in single cell. It will output whole list in a row, like this:

1 | Amazon | Product A | $100 | Amazon | Best Buy | Target

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$6;SMALL(IF(($B$1:$B$6=$B1)*($C$1:$C$6<>"na");ROW($A$1:$A$6));COLUMN($1:$6));1));"";INDEX($A$1:$B$6;SMALL(IF(($B$1:$B$6=$B1)*($C$1:$C$6<>"na");ROW($A$1:$A$6));COLUMN($1:$6));1))
```

But be aware that this is an array formula so there is some difficulties, like:

- Ctrl+Shift+Enter to execute instead of Enter
- You should select a range for formula to execute, because it returns an array.
- If you want to change the formula don't forget to do Ctrl+Shift+Enter or you will see an error about changing only part of an array

Using the table with data in your question - this is what you have to do:

1. put it in D1
2. select D1 and with CTRL+Shift+Right Arrow to select whole row
3. press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Now every column after D contains a value from the list you seek

4. after step 3 when row is still selected you should doubleclick the small square in the right bottom of the selection. This will fill and automatically calculate all rows from 1 to 6.

Formula assumes than "na" is used to fail the check. Be aware that I used <>, so it is an exact match (no spaces before or after)

Comment: This is also not what I need. We will potentially have too many values expanding out to more columns. Thank you, though.